# How to skip all roles and run all tasks without tagging

Tags: ansible

When I'm writing a playbook I need to run all tasks repeatedly. I could tag all `tasks` (and/or `roles`) to selectively run these using `--tags`. But what if I just want to run all `tasks` skipping all `roles`? Is there no shortcut for that that does not require tagging everything?

Given a playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: example playbook
  become: true
  hosts:
    - worker

  roles:
    - dev-sec.ssh-hardening
    - iptables

  tasks:
    - name: install pip3
      apt: name=python3-pip state=present

    - name: install kas via pip
      pip:
        name: kas
        state: present
```

something like

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yml my-example-playbook.yml --skip-all-roles
```

to skip all roles and only run the `tasks` of the playbook `my-example-playbook.yml` without tagging tasks.

Comment: Roles contain tasks. So running all tasks means you will run those in roles as well. Which tasks do you want to run exactly? Please create a [Minimal complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve) to ground your question to a real life example.

Comment: Added an example. The aim is to run **only** the tasks of the given playbook.

Comment: Regarding tasks, you don't have to tag them all one by one, you could just wrap them all in a block and tag the block

Comment: Nice! That simplifies things already quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two other ways — the second one would work without any change, but presuppose a specific playbook structure:

1. Instead of tagging a bunch of tasks, mind that you can tag a block:

   ```yaml
   - hosts: worker
     become: true

     roles:
       - dev-sec.ssh-hardening
       - iptables

     tasks:
       - block:
         - name: install pip3
           apt: 
             name: python3-pip 
             state: present

         - name: install kas via pip
           pip:
             name: kas
             state: present

         tags: only-tasks
   ```

   And, run it with

   ```bash
   ansible-playbook play.yml --tags only-tasks
   ```
2. Without changing anything, presuposing your roles are always before your tasks and that you know the name of the first task, you can use the [`--start-at-task`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_startnstep.html#start-at-task) flag, so in your case:

   ```bash
   ansible-playbook play.yml --start-at-task "install pip3"
   ```

Answer (score 3):

A simple workaround:

```yaml
---
- name: example playbook
  become: true
  hosts:
    - worker

  roles:
    - role: some_role
      when: not skip_roles | default(false) | bool

  tasks:
    - name: a playbook task
      debug:
        msg: a simple task
```

If you don't want to have all role tasks appearing as skipped (i.e. completely skip the role) you can try the following

```yaml
---
- name: example playbook
  become: true
  hosts:
    - worker

  tasks:
    - name: run some_role
      include_role:
        name: some_role
      when: not skip_roles | default(false) | bool

    - name: a playbook task
      debug:
        msg: a simple task
```

With either solution you can then run your playbook as:

```
# Run normally with all roles
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory my_playbook.yml

# Run skipping roles
ansible-playbook -i my_inventory -e skip_roles=true my_playbook.yml
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! For others, please also not the comment by β.εηοιτ.βε suggesting to wrap tasks in a `block` which does the job for me.